# Updating Bitnami Gitlab - Documentation lacking clarity

Tags: git, gitlab, bitnami

I'm trying to update a local installation of GitLab CE from v8.9.6 to v8.13.1 following [this guide](https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/apps/gitlab/#step-2-update-gitlab-code)

I've done the first bit on the second step:

```
cd /opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/htdocs
git fetch --all
git checkout -- db/schema.rb Gemfile.lock
```

Then on the next part I try to checkout to v8.13.1 and get the following error:

[image: gitlabupdate]

So the documentation appears to be missing a step.

There are around 100 repositories on this installation so I'm treading extremely careful despite having backups but evidentally I need to stash and apply.

Anyone have any insight on what the missing step may be or am I misreading this documentation somehow

**git diff**

```
reece@stead-lane-gitlab-vm:/opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/htdocs$ git diff
diff --git a/Gemfile b/Gemfile
index 7786982..55cd68c 100644
--- a/Gemfile
+++ b/Gemfile
@@ -29,7 +29,7 @@ gem 'omniauth-facebook',      '~> 3.0.0'
 gem 'omniauth-github',        '~> 1.1.1'
 gem 'omniauth-gitlab',        '~> 1.0.0'
 gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2', '~> 0.2.0'
-gem 'omniauth-kerberos',      '~> 0.3.0', group: :kerberos
+#gem 'omniauth-kerberos',      '~> 0.3.0', group: :kerberos
 gem 'omniauth-saml',          '~> 1.6.0'
 gem 'omniauth-shibboleth',    '~> 1.2.0'
 gem 'omniauth-twitter',       '~> 1.2.0'
diff --git a/app/helpers/commits_helper.rb b/app/helpers/commits_helper.rb
index 474041e..653ba3c 100644
--- a/app/helpers/commits_helper.rb
+++ b/app/helpers/commits_helper.rb
@@ -1,4 +1,5 @@
 # encoding: utf-8
+# encoding: utf-8
 module CommitsHelper
   # Returns a link to the commit author. If the author has a matching user and
   # is a member of the current @project it will link to the team member page.
diff --git a/bin/mail_room b/bin/mail_room
index 74a84f5..618c949 100755
--- a/bin/mail_room
+++ b/bin/mail_room
@@ -1,50 +1,16 @@
-#!/bin/sh
+#!/usr/bin/env ruby
+#
+# This file was generated by Bundler.
+#
+# The application 'mail_room' is installed as part of a gem, and
+# this file is here to facilitate running it.
+#

-cd $(dirname $0)/..
-app_root=$(pwd)
+require 'pathname'
+ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path("../../Gemfile",
+  Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath)
:...skipping...
diff --git a/Gemfile b/Gemfile
index 7786982..55cd68c 100644
--- a/Gemfile
+++ b/Gemfile
@@ -29,7 +29,7 @@ gem 'omniauth-facebook',      '~> 3.0.0'
 gem 'omniauth-github',        '~> 1.1.1'
 gem 'omniauth-gitlab',        '~> 1.0.0'
 gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2', '~> 0.2.0'
-gem 'omniauth-kerberos',      '~> 0.3.0', group: :kerberos
+#gem 'omniauth-kerberos',      '~> 0.3.0', group: :kerberos
 gem 'omniauth-saml',          '~> 1.6.0'
 gem 'omniauth-shibboleth',    '~> 1.2.0'
 gem 'omniauth-twitter',       '~> 1.2.0'
diff --git a/app/helpers/commits_helper.rb b/app/helpers/commits_helper.rb
index 474041e..653ba3c 100644
--- a/app/helpers/commits_helper.rb
+++ b/app/helpers/commits_helper.rb
@@ -1,4 +1,5 @@
 # encoding: utf-8
+# encoding: utf-8
 module CommitsHelper
   # Returns a link to the commit author. If the author has a matching user and
   # is a member of the current @project it will link to the team member page.
diff --git a/bin/mail_room b/bin/mail_room
index 74a84f5..618c949 100755
--- a/bin/mail_room
+++ b/bin/mail_room
@@ -1,50 +1,16 @@
-#!/bin/sh
+#!/usr/bin/env ruby
+#
+# This file was generated by Bundler.
+#
+# The application 'mail_room' is installed as part of a gem, and
+# this file is here to facilitate running it.
+#

-cd $(dirname $0)/..
-app_root=$(pwd)
+require 'pathname'
+ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path("../../Gemfile",
+  Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath)

-mail_room_pidfile="$app_root/tmp/pids/mail_room.pid"
-mail_room_logfile="$app_root/log/mail_room.log"
:...skipping...
diff --git a/Gemfile b/Gemfile
index 7786982..55cd68c 100644
--- a/Gemfile
+++ b/Gemfile
@@ -29,7 +29,7 @@ gem 'omniauth-facebook',      '~> 3.0.0'
 gem 'omniauth-github',        '~> 1.1.1'
 gem 'omniauth-gitlab',        '~> 1.0.0'
 gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2', '~> 0.2.0'
-gem 'omniauth-kerberos',      '~> 0.3.0', group: :kerberos
+#gem 'omniauth-kerberos',      '~> 0.3.0', group: :kerberos
 gem 'omniauth-saml',          '~> 1.6.0'
 gem 'omniauth-shibboleth',    '~> 1.2.0'
 gem 'omniauth-twitter',       '~> 1.2.0'
diff --git a/app/helpers/commits_helper.rb b/app/helpers/commits_helper.rb
index 474041e..653ba3c 100644
--- a/app/helpers/commits_helper.rb
+++ b/app/helpers/commits_helper.rb
@@ -1,4 +1,5 @@
 # encoding: utf-8
+# encoding: utf-8
 module CommitsHelper
   # Returns a link to the commit author. If the author has a matching user and
   # is a member of the current @project it will link to the team member page.
diff --git a/bin/mail_room b/bin/mail_room
index 74a84f5..618c949 100755
--- a/bin/mail_room
+++ b/bin/mail_room
@@ -1,50 +1,16 @@
-#!/bin/sh
+#!/usr/bin/env ruby
+#
+# This file was generated by Bundler.
+#
+# The application 'mail_room' is installed as part of a gem, and
+# this file is here to facilitate running it.
+#

-cd $(dirname $0)/..
-app_root=$(pwd)
+require 'pathname'
+ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path("../../Gemfile",
+  Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath)

-mail_room_pidfile="$app_root/tmp/pids/mail_room.pid"
-mail_room_logfile="$app_root/log/mail_room.log"
-mail_room_config="$app_root/config/mail_room.yml"
+require 'rubygems'
+require 'bundler/setup'

-get_mail_room_pid()
-{
:...skipping...
diff --git a/Gemfile b/Gemfile
index 7786982..55cd68c 100644
--- a/Gemfile
+++ b/Gemfile
@@ -29,7 +29,7 @@ gem 'omniauth-facebook',      '~> 3.0.0'
 gem 'omniauth-github',        '~> 1.1.1'
 gem 'omniauth-gitlab',        '~> 1.0.0'
 gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2', '~> 0.2.0'
-gem 'omniauth-kerberos',      '~> 0.3.0', group: :kerberos
+#gem 'omniauth-kerberos',      '~> 0.3.0', group: :kerberos
 gem 'omniauth-saml',          '~> 1.6.0'
 gem 'omniauth-shibboleth',    '~> 1.2.0'
 gem 'omniauth-twitter',       '~> 1.2.0'
diff --git a/app/helpers/commits_helper.rb b/app/helpers/commits_helper.rb
index 474041e..653ba3c 100644
--- a/app/helpers/commits_helper.rb
+++ b/app/helpers/commits_helper.rb
@@ -1,4 +1,5 @@
 # encoding: utf-8
+# encoding: utf-8
 module CommitsHelper
   # Returns a link to the commit author. If the author has a matching user and
   # is a member of the current @project it will link to the team member page.
diff --git a/bin/mail_room b/bin/mail_room
index 74a84f5..618c949 100755
--- a/bin/mail_room
+++ b/bin/mail_room
@@ -1,50 +1,16 @@
-#!/bin/sh
+#!/usr/bin/env ruby
+#
+# This file was generated by Bundler.
+#
+# The application 'mail_room' is installed as part of a gem, and
+# this file is here to facilitate running it.
+#

-cd $(dirname $0)/..
-app_root=$(pwd)
+require 'pathname'
+ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path("../../Gemfile",
+  Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath)

-mail_room_pidfile="$app_root/tmp/pids/mail_room.pid"
-mail_room_logfile="$app_root/log/mail_room.log"
-mail_room_config="$app_root/config/mail_room.yml"
+require 'rubygems'
+require 'bundler/setup'

-get_mail_room_pid()
-{
-  local pid=$(cat $mail_room_pidfile)
-  if [ -z "$pid" ] ; then
-    echo "Could not find a PID in $mail_room_pidfile"
-    exit 1
-  fi
-  mail_room_pid=$pid
-}
:...skipping...
diff --git a/Gemfile b/Gemfile
index 7786982..55cd68c 100644
--- a/Gemfile
+++ b/Gemfile
@@ -29,7 +29,7 @@ gem 'omniauth-facebook',      '~> 3.0.0'
 gem 'omniauth-github',        '~> 1.1.1'
 gem 'omniauth-gitlab',        '~> 1.0.0'
 gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2', '~> 0.2.0'
-gem 'omniauth-kerberos',      '~> 0.3.0', group: :kerberos
+#gem 'omniauth-kerberos',      '~> 0.3.0', group: :kerberos
 gem 'omniauth-saml',          '~> 1.6.0'
 gem 'omniauth-shibboleth',    '~> 1.2.0'
 gem 'omniauth-twitter',       '~> 1.2.0'
diff --git a/app/helpers/commits_helper.rb b/app/helpers/commits_helper.rb
index 474041e..653ba3c 100644
--- a/app/helpers/commits_helper.rb
+++ b/app/helpers/commits_helper.rb
@@ -1,4 +1,5 @@
 # encoding: utf-8
+# encoding: utf-8
 module CommitsHelper
   # Returns a link to the commit author. If the author has a matching user and
   # is a member of the current @project it will link to the team member page.
diff --git a/bin/mail_room b/bin/mail_room
index 74a84f5..618c949 100755
--- a/bin/mail_room
+++ b/bin/mail_room
@@ -1,50 +1,16 @@
-#!/bin/sh
+#!/usr/bin/env ruby
+#
+# This file was generated by Bundler.
+#
+# The application 'mail_room' is installed as part of a gem, and
+# this file is here to facilitate running it.
+#

-cd $(dirname $0)/..
-app_root=$(pwd)
+require 'pathname'
+ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path("../../Gemfile",
+  Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath)

-mail_room_pidfile="$app_root/tmp/pids/mail_room.pid"
-mail_room_logfile="$app_root/log/mail_room.log"
-mail_room_config="$app_root/config/mail_room.yml"
+require 'rubygems'
+require 'bundler/setup'

-get_mail_room_pid()
-{
-  local pid=$(cat $mail_room_pidfile)
-  if [ -z "$pid" ] ; then
-    echo "Could not find a PID in $mail_room_pidfile"
-    exit 1
-  fi
-  mail_room_pid=$pid
-}
-
-start()
-{
-  bin/daemon_with_pidfile $mail_room_pidfile bundle exec mail_room -q -c $mail_room_config >> $mail_room_logfile 2>&1
-}
:...skipping...
diff --git a/Gemfile b/Gemfile
index 7786982..55cd68c 100644
--- a/Gemfile
+++ b/Gemfile
@@ -29,7 +29,7 @@ gem 'omniauth-facebook',      '~> 3.0.0'
 gem 'omniauth-github',        '~> 1.1.1'
 gem 'omniauth-gitlab',        '~> 1.0.0'
 gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2', '~> 0.2.0'
-gem 'omniauth-kerberos',      '~> 0.3.0', group: :kerberos
+#gem 'omniauth-kerberos',      '~> 0.3.0', group: :kerberos
 gem 'omniauth-saml',          '~> 1.6.0'
 gem 'omniauth-shibboleth',    '~> 1.2.0'
 gem 'omniauth-twitter',       '~> 1.2.0'
diff --git a/app/helpers/commits_helper.rb b/app/helpers/commits_helper.rb
index 474041e..653ba3c 100644
--- a/app/helpers/commits_helper.rb
+++ b/app/helpers/commits_helper.rb
@@ -1,4 +1,5 @@
 # encoding: utf-8
+# encoding: utf-8
 module CommitsHelper
   # Returns a link to the commit author. If the author has a matching user and
   # is a member of the current @project it will link to the team member page.
diff --git a/bin/mail_room b/bin/mail_room
index 74a84f5..618c949 100755
--- a/bin/mail_room
+++ b/bin/mail_room
@@ -1,50 +1,16 @@
-#!/bin/sh
+#!/usr/bin/env ruby
+#
+# This file was generated by Bundler.
+#
+# The application 'mail_room' is installed as part of a gem, and
+# this file is here to facilitate running it.
+#

-cd $(dirname $0)/..
-app_root=$(pwd)
+require 'pathname'
+ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path("../../Gemfile",
+  Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath)

-mail_room_pidfile="$app_root/tmp/pids/mail_room.pid"
-mail_room_logfile="$app_root/log/mail_room.log"
-mail_room_config="$app_root/config/mail_room.yml"
+require 'rubygems'
+require 'bundler/setup'

-get_mail_room_pid()
-{
-  local pid=$(cat $mail_room_pidfile)
-  if [ -z "$pid" ] ; then
-    echo "Could not find a PID in $mail_room_pidfile"
-    exit 1
-  fi
-  mail_room_pid=$pid
-}
-
-start()
-{
-  bin/daemon_with_pidfile $mail_room_pidfile bundle exec mail_room -q -c $mail_room_config >> $mail_room_logfile 2>&1
-}
-
-stop()
-{
```

Comment: did you happen to modify those three files manually? if so, then the most common would of course to `stash` and `pop` it.

Comment: No I definitely did not touch/modify anything, followed the instructions to the tee without straying off-course and have been led to the above issue unfortunately.

Comment: Looking at the guide, for the `Gemfile`, it is possible to be different with the HEAD because bitnami will use it for offline installation. About the other two files, can you try to check whether there is a difference with the HEAD or is it just a difference in whitespace?

Comment: Thanks for investigating @kucing_terbang I ran `git diff` and updated my question with the response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is due to, as you say, a lack of clarity in our documents. We are sorry about it, and will make sure to make it clearer as soon as we can.

There is something else we should correct. In step 6, you'll have to execute a `bundle` command, and it's very likely to crash. That is because we told you to exit the `git` user, but this is required later on. Because of this, execute `sudo su git` before executing that.

Thanks for using our products! I hope my solution helps you.

EDIT: The corrections that must be performed in order to migrate to 8.13.1 are:

Versions for raindrops, unicorn and unicorn-worker-killer gems must be changed in Gemfile.lock and Gemfile, since latest version builds crash with our ruby version. Raindrops must use `0.15.0`, Unicorn should use `0.4.9` and Unicorn-worker-killer `0.4.2`.

Before performing the checkout step in step 2, you must stash your changes with `git stash`, perform the checkout and pop the stashed content, solving any merging issue that arises. (I only had to execute `git rm /opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/htdocs/config/gitlab.yml.example` to do that).

Comment: Not sure whats going on here, I followed the instructions (merged with yours) perfectly, I got through all the steps this time however my Gitlab version is still 8.9.6 when I wanted 8.13.1

Comment: The only location where it mentions anything about the `target version` (8.13.1) is step 7. Should an entire step be inbetween step 7 and step 8? It's got me comparing configuration files from current <-> target version but I don't see any step where I actually get anything from 8.13-stable

Comment: Hi again, sorry for the late reply. I'm updating the original reply with the right answer to the upgrade process. Could you please check that out? Please let us know if you find any issue in the process. I could update to 8.13.1 without issues.

Comment: Thanks dave, upgraded fine now! appreciate your time

Comment: Would a shell script be too much to ask? Is there any reason why this all can't be consolidated into a single script that a user can upgrade to the latest stable version at any given time? It's kind of a "goodbye bitnami, you're too difficult" deal.

Answer (score 0):

I try to summarize the complete process modifications.

On step 2, replace `git checkout v8.x.y` by:

```
git stash
git checkout v8.x.y
git stash apply
```

Something not clear at step 4: the bitnami bundle has go 1.5.3.
Do I really need go 1.6 ?

Also, the downloaded go **must** be in /usr/local, it has hard-coded things that depends on `/usr/local/go`. You can't install it anywhere else.

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin` should be `export PATH=/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH` so that the new installed go takes precedence over the go from the system.

On step 6, you should begin with being user "git":

```
sudo su git
bundle install --without development test mysql --deployment
```

But then:

```
bitnami@git:/opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/htdocs$ sudo su git
git@git:/opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/htdocs$ bundle install --without development test mysql --deployment
Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile. We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

You have deleted from the Gemfile:
* omniauth-kerberos (~> 0.3.0)
```

Something else missing?

Comment: I uncommented the `gem 'omniauth-kerberos',      '~> 0.3.0', group: :kerberos` line in the Gemfile, and the gems have been installed properly....

Answer (score 0):

As ofaurax said you have to uncomment the gem

```
'omniauth-kerberos', '~> 0.3.0', group: :kerberos
```

**OR** to have the kerberos installed library with something like (depend your distro) :

```
sudo apt-get install -y libpam-krb5 libkrb5-dev`.
```

What about upgrade from 8.13 to 8.14 ?

We have to make the same trick in Gemfile.lock:

```
raindrops (0.15.0)
unicorn (0.4.9)
unicorn-worker-killer (0.4.2)
```

**BUT**

The Kanban board return a 404 (thats one of the errors...)

Same question as Zanderwar. 
When bitnami team should provide a fix and a packaged upgrade plan from 8.11 to greater ?